# Deploy with Maven Inside Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am attempting to deploy with maven inside eclipse Version: 2021-06 (4.20.0)
Build id: 20210612-2011 after upgrading Eclipse when CodeMix ruined my previous eclipse install (whihc worked).  I can successfully deploy from the command line and I have set Eclipse to read my settings file:

```
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from C:\Users\neilb\.m2\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from C:\Users\neilb\.m2\settings.xml
```

The pom is pointing to the correct repos and the details in the settings are correct and we know this because it deploys in the console.  However when I try to deploy inside Eclipse I get a 401:

```
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) artifact = com.ziath.datapaq:scanner:jar:1.5.29
[DEBUG]   (f) attachedArtifacts = []
[DEBUG]   (s) localRepository =       id: local
      url: file:///C:/Users/neilb/.m2/repository/
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => true, update => always]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => always]
   blocked: false

[DEBUG]   (f) offline = false
[DEBUG]   (f) packaging = jar
[DEBUG]   (f) pomFile = C:\Users\neilb\Documents\GitHub\scanner\pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: com.ziath.datapaq:scanner:1.5.29 @ C:\Users\neilb\Documents\GitHub\scanner\pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) retryFailedDeploymentCount = 1
[DEBUG]   (f) skip = false
[DEBUG]   (f) updateReleaseInfo = false
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] Using connector AetherRepositoryConnector with priority 100.0 for http://10.9.8.246:8081/repository/lib-releases/ with username=admin, password=***
[INFO] Uploading to : http://10.9.8.246:8081/repository/lib-releases/com/ziath/datapaq/scanner/1.5.29/scanner-1.5.29.pom
[INFO] Uploading to : http://10.9.8.246:8081/repository/lib-releases/com/ziath/datapaq/scanner/1.5.29/scanner-1.5.29.jar
[INFO] Uploaded to : http://10.9.8.246:8081/repository/lib-releases/com/ziath/datapaq/scanner/1.5.29/scanner-1.5.29.pom (10 kB at 92 kB/s)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

The exception is as follows:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project scanner: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.ziath.datapaq:scanner:jar:1.5.29 from/to releases (http://10.9.8.246:8081/repository/lib-releases/): Access denied to http://10.9.8.246:8081/repository/lib-releases/com/ziath/datapaq/scanner/1.5.29/scanner-1.5.29.jar. Error code 401, Unauthorized -> [Help 1]
```

Has anyone any idea as to what needs to be changed in order to get deployment from Eclipse version 2021-06 to work?

Cheers,

Neil

Comment: are you sure you have access here

Comment: http://10.9.8.246:8081

Comment: Yes because it works from the command line - this is our Nexus repository.  It also worked on the old Eclipse install - reinstalling eclipse caused the break.  In addition we can upload the POM; it is the jar which will not upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug:

https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/issues/250

There are workarounds listed there; so to the person who downgraded the question - ya boo sucks!